# Find The Max Value And From A Column That Also Contains Text

Tags: excel, vba, search, max, numeric

I'm trying to create a macro that would find the maximum numerical value in a column (which also contains text) and inserts a new row with that value +1.

For some reason it won't work and just keeps the original number, it also messes up the conditional formatting I have in column D even if that column is locked.

```
Sub_Move()

Set wk1 = Sheet1
Set wk2 = Sheet4
Set wk3 = Sheet5

Dim mynumber As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheet1.Unprotect
Sheet4.Unprotect
Sheet5.Unprotect

mynumber = 1
'Move-Characterisation'
Worksheets("Characterisation").Activate
For i = 1000 To 15 Step -1
    If Range("W" & i).Value = "Completed" Then
    Worksheets("Burn").Activate
    Range("B15:W15").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("B15:W15").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

    End If

    Worksheets("Characterisation").Activate
    If Range("W" & i).Value = "Completed" Then
    Range("W" & i).Select
    Range("W" & i).Value = "Delete"
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, -21)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Worksheets("Burn").Activate
    Range("B15").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("W15").ClearContents

    **MaxVal1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(wk2.Range("D15:D1000"))
    Range("D15").Value = MaxVal1 + 1**

    End If

    Worksheets("Characterisation").Activate
    If Range("W" & i).Value = "Delete" Then
    Range("W" & i).Select
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, -21)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    End If

    Next
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.Max()` will already get the maximum value in a range considering numeric values only. So what's your real problem?

Comment: also, `Range(D15).Value = MaxVal + 1` should be `Range("D15").Value = MaxVal1 + 1`

Comment: Oh right, thanks. I thought that if I use MaxVal1+1 it might enter a value of text and then just +1.